# Diff patch from a single file?

Tags: diff, patch

I'm looking at a diff patch file provided by Magento and it looks something like this:

```
--- downloader/Maged/Controller.php
+++ downloader/Maged/Controller.php
@@ -1017,7 +1017,7 @@ final class Maged_Controller
             'major'     => '1',
             'minor'     => '14',
             'revision'  => '0',
-            'patch'     => '0',
+            'patch'     => '1',
             'stability' => '',
             'number'    => '',
         );
```

look at the first two lines - how did they do that? shouldn't source and target be different?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this using SVN's create patch functionality.